# Relationship into table (ER-model into relational model)

Tags: database, sqlite, entity-relationship

I am trying to transform ER-model to Relational model and then to SQlite3 code.

In the ER-model I write the relationship for example:

Customer - has - Order

(Where Customer and Order are entities. Has is the relationship)

**I know I need to transform the entities into tables and their attributes to fields of that table**

**But, should I create a table of the "has" relationship between "Order" and "Customer" -entities?**

I should, According to this article: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/mapping-from-er-model-to-relational-model/amp/

Comment: Actually, the thing is that I thought I always could just create tables of the entities with SQlite, add the foreign keys and then just populate the tables with data. Now, it seems that is not sufficient, and I would need to code the 'has' table as well in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question comes down to the **relationship type** (1-to-1, 1-to-many, or many-to-many).

**Quick Answer:** In general, we only need a relationship table** when the relationship type is many-to-many.

- For **1-to-1** or **1-to-many**, we **don't have to and shouldn't** create a relationship table.
- For **many-to-many**, we **must** create a relationship table.

---

**Examples:**

For example, say the relationship is **1-to-many** (one customer can have many orders). Then, we can add the entity's primary key (pk) on the "1" side as a foreign key (fk) on the "many" side.

```
Customer: (<customer_id_pk>, <other_fields>)

Order:    (<order_id_pk>, <other_fields>, <customer_id_fk>)
```

In another example, say the relationship is **many-to-many** (customers can have many orders, and many customers can share one order for whatever reason). Then, we will need another table to represent the relationship.

```
Customer: (<customer_id>, <other_fields>)

Order:    (<order_id>, <other_fields>)

Customer_Order_Relationship: (<customer_id>, <order_id>)
```